# XMLHttpRequest stops when my panel loses focus in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am sending a xmlhttprequest from my google chrome ui after a button is pressed in the popup.html. This code works fine as long as the popup.html remains open. But the moment the popup.html closes(bu clciking the mouse outside popup.html area) the xmlhttprequest automatically aborts and stops. This causes my program to stop execution. I want to know if there is any way in which i can continue the xmlhttprequest even if the windows gets hidden and loses focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AJAX request should be done by a background script. Execution of this script can not be stopped easily by the user.

You should modify your extension like this:

- user clicks something in the popup
- popup calls a function from a [background page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getBackgroundPage)
- *(from this place on popup is no longer needed to be open)*
- background page sends an AJAX call and retrieves the answer
- *(background page may ignore/store the answer form AJAX call or pass it to some content script/popup script etc.)*

Comment: so i should create a background.html and call the background.html from the popup like this:chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().testRequest(); or is it something else you mean

Comment: But background pages are always active and run all the time. I dont think this functionality is desired in my application. Is there any other way to achive this.

Comment: Yes they do run in the background all the time but there is nothing wrong with them. They do not require additional permissions and do not use up much resources when idle. Anyway, I don't think you have any other reasonable options here.